# What does Mongoose update() really update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The Mongoose docs [mention](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) this example code:

```
Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  tank.size = 'large';
  tank.save(function (err, updatedTank) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(updatedTank);
  });
});
```

Does this result to a MongoDB [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command setting just the `size` property (i.e. `db.tanks.update({_id: tank._id}, {$set: {size: "large"}});`) or does this replace the whole document?

Or, with other words, what if another client updates another property (let's say, `color`) just after `findById()` returns but before before `save()` is executed? Is `color` then reverted to the previous value or kept intact?

And, in case Mongoose is smart enough to update only "changed" properties, how exactly is that detected (values being compared before/after? or via a setter on the `tank` object?)? What if the tank `size` was already "large" anyway?

I'm asking because the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) are not very clear on this and I'd like to understand how Mongoose is *designed* and *intended to be used* in this regard.

Comment: Should be relatively easy to test yourself.

Comment: Not if I don't have a database to test with. Also, testing does not exactly reveal what a library is *supposed* to do. A bad test can lead to false assumptions.

Comment: I doubt that you'll be getting a definitive answer from anyone besides the developer of Mongoose on what is _supposed_ to happen, esp since the documentation isn't definitive. Answers posted here by regular users will be anecdotal.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of testing shows that Mongoose tracks modifications to documents (by using setters, as you already mentioned), and will run an update that `$set`'s the new values.

So this:

```
tank.size = 'large';
tank.save(...);
```

Is (roughly speaking) implemented as:

```
tankCollection.update({ _id : tank._id }, { $set : { size : 'large' } }, ...);
```

If the previous value of `size` was also `large`, it won't perform the update. Also, if the document is new, it will run a different code path (calling `tankCollection.insert()`).

So concurrent updates should work, provided that they don't update the same property (in which case the last performed update wins).